# Bad SVG when two TikZ pictures are placed side by side in a figure environment - make4ht

Tags: tikz-pgf, tex4ht, make4ht, dvisvgm

When I use `make4ht index.tex "xhtml"` to compile the file

```
\documentclass{report}
\ifdefined\HCode
    \def\pgfsysdriver{pgfsys-dvisvgm4ht.def}
\fi
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
        \begin{center}
            \begin{tikzpicture}
                \draw (0,0) rectangle (3,3);
            \end{tikzpicture}
            \begin{tikzpicture}
                \draw (0,0) rectangle (3,3);
            \end{tikzpicture}
        \end{center}
        \caption{Test.\label{fig:test}}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

the SVG file corresponding to the second rectangle does not compile correctly, so it is not rendered. If I place the two rectangles one below the other instead of side by side (by adding a blank line between the two TikZ pictures)

```
\documentclass{report}
\ifdefined\HCode
    \def\pgfsysdriver{pgfsys-dvisvgm4ht.def}
\fi
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
        \begin{center}
            \begin{tikzpicture}
                \draw (0,0) rectangle (3,3);
            \end{tikzpicture}

            \begin{tikzpicture}
                \draw (0,0) rectangle (3,3);
            \end{tikzpicture}
        \end{center}
        \caption{Test.\label{fig:test}}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

then everything works as expected. The PDF compiles correctly using `pdflatex` in either case. Is this a bug, either in `tex4ht` or in [the `dvisvgm` driver](https://github.com/michal-h21/dvisvgm4ht), or am I not using it right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug in the `dvisvgm4ht` driver. It uses different TeX4ht commands for converting TeX code to images depending on the vertical mode. It should run the same command in all cases. Here is the updated version:

```
% Copyright 2020 by Michal Hoftich
% Copyright 2006 by Till Tantau
%
% This file may be distributed and/or modified
%
% 1. under the LaTeX Project Public License and/or
% 2. under the GNU Public License.
%
% See the file doc/generic/pgf/licenses/LICENSE for more details.

\ProvidesFileRCS{pgfsys-dvisvgm4ht.def}

% Driver commands for tex4ht

%
% Load common pdf commands:
%

% we load the dvips driver by default. it doesn't support patterns and some other stuff,
% but it handles better nested images and some formatting. if you use patterns or if you
% have other issues with the default method, pass the "tikz-dvisvgm" option to make4ht. 
\ifdefined\ifOption
\ifOption{tikz+}{\input pgfsys-dvisvgm.def}{\input pgfsys-dvips.def}
\else
% load the dvips driver by default
\input pgfsys-dvips.def
\fi


\def\texfourht@tikz@begin{%
  \bgroup%
  \def\run@pict@cmd{}% insert the \Picture hooks only in the top nesting level
  \def\end@pict@cmd{}%
  \ifdefined\EndPicture\else% We are already inside command that uses \Picture
  \ifdefined\inside@pict@cmd% handle nested uses
  \else
  % use different version of \Picture depending on the vertical mode
  \run@pict@cmd{\Picture*}%
  \def\end@pict@cmd{\EndPicture}%
  \fi\fi%
  % command used to detect nesting
  \def\inside@pict@cmd{}%
  \csname a:tikzpicture\endcsname%
}

\def\texfourht@tikz@end{%
  \csname b:tikzpicture\endcsname%
  \egroup%
}

\AtBeginDocument{
  \NewConfigure{tikzpicture}{2}
  \catcode`\:=11
  \Configure{tikzpicture}{%
    \protect\csname nested:math\endcsname% support display math
    \run@pict@cmd{}%
  }{\end@pict@cmd}
  % configure the output picture format to svg, as it will require dvisvgm
  % post processing. 
  \Configure{Picture}{.svg}
  % insert tex4ht hooks around TikZ picture box
  \def\pgfsys@typesetpicturebox#1{%
    \texfourht@tikz@begin%
    \orig@pgfsys@typesetpicturebox{#1}%
    \texfourht@tikz@end%
  }
  %
  \ConfigureEnv{tikzpicture}{\Picture*{}\def\inside@pict@cmd{}}{\EndPicture}{}{}
  \ConfigureEnv{pgfpicture}{\Picture*{}\def\inside@pict@cmd{}}{\EndPicture}{}{}
  \catcode`\:=12
}


% Make the code inserted by tex4ht configurable
% 


\let\orig@pgfsys@typesetpicturebox\pgfsys@typesetpicturebox
%\def\pgf@sys@postscript@header#1{{\special{! #1}}}


\endinput


%%% Local Variables:
%%% mode: latex
%%% End:
```

To get the figures side by side, use this configuration file:

```
\Preamble{xhtml}
\Css{figure.float img, figure.figure img {display: inline;}}
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

This is the result:
[image]

Comment: That fixes it, but now these are not side by side like they are in the `pdf`. I suppose I have to force that using `minipages`?

Comment: @Rushi no, just simple CSS is needed. See the edited answer.